# Conversion of php multidimensional array to javascript array

Tags: javascript, php

I have encoded a set of multidimensional array from the php and i echo to the ajax. 
Now the response looks like the following

```
 Array
(    
    [0]=>Array
         ([messagebody]=>hello
          [senderid]=>2
          [receiverid]=4
          )
   [1]=>Array
         ([messagebody]=>how are you
          [senderid]=>4
          [receiverid]=2
          )
    )
```

Please how do i access this array in javascript to get the messagebody?

Comment: Have you tried [encoding for JSON](https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be `print_r()` your arrays as this it produces human readable output, nothing JS can deal with easily nor out of the box. Instead you should use i.e. [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and pass your arrays in that form to JS:

```
echo json_encode($my_array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```